# In Javascript is there a way to concatenate a string a certain multiple of times without using a loop?

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation

Let's say I want to concatenate a certain string, e.g. "#", a certain number of times, e.g. n=5. (the number of times, n, is variable.)

So for n=5, we would get: #####
but for n=2, we would get: ##
etc.

Is there a way to do this without using a loop?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using `String.prototype.repeat()`. According to `MDN`

> The `repeat()` method constructs and returns a new string which contains the specified number of copies of the string on which it was called, concatenated together.

It takes a `count` parameter as it's the only argument which is

> An integer between `0` and `+Infinity`, indicating the number of times to repeat the string.

And returns

> A new string containing the specified number of copies of the given string.

```js
let str = "#";
let newStr = str.repeat(5);
console.log(newStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [string.repeat(count)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat):

```js
console.log("#".repeat(5));
```